# Is Pope Francis with or against LGBT?

Tags: homosexuality

I'm not a native English speaker and I read in the news a lot of complicated expressions that makes me wonder if he's with LGBT or not.

There's only heavens and hell (Nothing is in between) so he must be with or against it.

I'm asking about his opinion because he's the head of the Catholic Church. I also heard that a church in the USA agreed on the marriage of a homosexual couple, is that correct? Can this be done without the permission of the Pope?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what sorts of things count as being with, or against, it. I don't think you can simply say "he must be with or against it" - he Catholic Church's position is a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: @JosephHinkle Comments are not for making assumptions about other peoples' beliefs nor giving spiritual advice.  Please focus on the question at hand.

Comment: "With or against" seems to be inciteful text.  Was it your intention to suggest that LGBT peoples and/or the LGBT political movement are a standard by which religion should be judged?  Or did you mean "supportive of or not supportive of," which suggests the application of Christian principles in regard to LGBT peoples and/or the LGBT political movement is a standard by which religion will be judged?

Comment: People on this site will try to dodge this question, "For they loved praise from men more than praise from God. "

Answer (score 5):

Your question is quite a basic one so let me try to cover some basic principles.

First, the question of being "with or against" LGBT is seriously oversimplifying the situation. There is much more to this than simply "is homosexuality good or bad?"

The Catholic church's position is and has been that homosexual sex acts and same-sex marriage are contrary to God's will. That is not the same as being "against LGBT". Someone with a homosexual orientation is not more sinful, or less loved by God, because of that. Pope Francis as Pope agrees with that.

What Francis is mainly talking about is the attitude of the church, and individual Christians, to people with homosexual orientation. Some churches take an attitude of nothing but condemnation, rejecting such people and everything to do with them outright, and distancing themselves in every way. What Pope Francis appears to be arguing for is an approach that admits God's love for those of homosexual orientation (as indeed God has love for everyone), and is tempered with understanding and compassion for the difficulties they face, and the potential for forgiveness. This can be done while not changing the doctrine of the church.

As for the churches you have heard about that conduct gay marriages, those are almost certainly not Catholic. A number of churches believe that homosexual marriage is permissible, but the Catholic church is not one.

Just to add that the 'T' in LGBT raises an entirely different set of issues, and if you want to know about it you should ask a separate question.

Comment: Very well said.

Comment: @DJClayworth what I can conclude from your answer is that the Pop implies that God loves homosexuals but hates the act of homosexuality (having sex) because God loves people but hates doing sins. Did I get you correctly?

Comment: That's a pretty good summary. He is also talking about how the church treats homosexuals too.